# How to validate textarea and checkboxes which are generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, checkbox

This one seems really common question in StackOverflow. However, I am having difficulty in validating these textarea (Not to left blank) and checkboxes(At least one should be checked). I tried several validation Javascripts and frameworks but in vain.

I have textarea named "case_title0[]" whose will increase the number "0" to "1","2" and so on when user clicks "Add More" button. I want to validate at the point when user clicks the "Add More" button.

Secondly, I want the checkbox (name="editioncheck'+caseNum+'[]") which is dynamic as well to restrict user to leave it blank. The checkbox looks like "editioncheck0[]", "editioncheck1[]" and so on. It needs to be checked at least once to proceed to next "Add More" button. Until then "Add More" button should remain inactive.

So, I want these two type of validation in my form ie. textarea and checkbox.

Which is the simplest framework or custom code to use here?

I don't want fancy display as just alert() box should work in this regard.

Comment: Have you tried jquery validation plugin?

Comment: Hi Bablu,i did but for some reason it was not working..

Comment: can you post some code here

Answer (score 1):

Add common class to all textareas and common class to all checkboxes and perform validation.

```
<textarea class="t"></textarea>
<textarea class="t"></textarea>
<textarea class="t"></textarea>
<textarea class="t"></textarea>

<input type="checkbox" class="c">

function validate() {
    var err = false;
    $('.t').each(function(){
         if($(this).text().length < 1) {
             err = true;
             return false;
         }
    });
    if(!err) {
         /* code to validate checkboxes like above */
    }
    return !err;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have figured out the solution and I am going to post it here. As there is no exactly similar solution to my problem I had to code from scratch. While doing so lot of online resources helped me a lot.

To validate textarea on the fly (dynamic generate of text area when user clicks "Add More" button), here is solution I applied:

```
        var csn='case_title'+caseno; //here "caseno" is incremental number to uniquely identify elements
        var csum='case_summary'+caseno;

        var caset=document.getElementById(csn).value;
        var casesum=document.getElementById(csum).value;

        if (caset == null || caset == "") {
         alert("Executive Summary must be filled out");
         caseNum --;
        return false;

        }

        if (casesum == null || casesum == "") {
         alert("Summaries with links must be filled out");
         caseNum --;
        return false;
```

Next, to validate the checkboxes I did as follows:

```
var edval='editioncheck'+caseno;
var checkBoxes=document.getElementsByClassName(edval);
        var isChecked = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
            if ( checkBoxes[i].checked ) {
                isChecked = true;
            };
        };

        if ( isChecked ) {
            //alert( 'At least one checkbox checked!' );
            } else {
                alert( 'Select at least one edition!' );
                caseNum --;
                return false;
            }
```

The solution seems similar to the concept of fr34k, so thanks a lot. However, I found this online here http://jsfiddle.net/qyE97/

So, every time user click "Add More" button this script is executed and validates for the textarea and checkboxes.

Comment: Hi Gibberish, I have upvoted the answer of Fr34k. Thanks for suggestion.